# converting long string to date

Tags: android, date

I am getting date value from DB as a **long** value. I am converting this to **string** to use *parse* function. Given below is my code

```
 Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(strDate1);
```

But the app is crashing when this code is executing.it will successfully execute if the

```
strDate1="12/30/2012".
```

But i am having this value as "**12302012235**"(pzudo value).

How can i do this?

**edit:**

i am saving date value to DB as INTEGER. from DB i am getting this value and converting to string.this is the actual strDate1 value

```
strDate1="1346524199000"
```

Comment: What *exactly* does your `long` value represent? What's it storing, and who's storing it? It makes a *big* difference if it's meant to be (say) "milliseconds since the Unix epoch" or some horrible pseudo-text numeric representation.

Comment: Can you just strip off the last 3 characters and then use your value?

Answer (score 5):

Try the following code segment:

```
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeInMillis(Long.parseLong(val));         
        Date d = (Date) c.getTime();        
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");       
        String time = format.format(d);//this variable time contains the time in the format of "day/month/year".
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date dateD=new Date();
    dateD.setTime(LongTime);
    date=dateFormat.format(dateD);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Java 8**, Convert milliseconds long to Date as String by given date format pattern. If you have a long milliseconds and want to convert them into date string at specifies time zone and pattern, then you can use it:-

**dateInMs** is a long value of DateTime.

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                    .format(Instant.ofEpochMilli(dateInMs).atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")))
```

Answer (score 2):

### *java.time*

The `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> .

**Using modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long input = 12302012235L;

        // Get Instant from input
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(input);
        System.out.println(instant);

        // Convert Instant to ZonedDateTime by applying time-zone
        // Change ZoneId as applicable e.g. ZoneId.of("Asia/Dubai")
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // Format ZonedDateTime as desired
        // Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573 to learn more about 'u'
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatted = dtf.format(zdt);
        System.out.println(formatted);

        // If at all, you need java.util.Date
        Date date = Date.from(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1970-05-23T09:13:32.235Z
1970-05-23T10:13:32.235+01:00[Europe/London]
05/23/1970
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code:

```
private Date getGMTDate(long date) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatGmt = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    dateFormatGmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    Date temp = new Date(date);

    try {
        return dateFormatLocal.parse(dateFormatGmt.format(temp));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return temp;
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyySSS").parse(strDate1);
```

Hope it will works for 12302012235 , but i assume 235 is millisec.

Answer (score 0):

i got the answer.actually i wanted to convert the string to date only for comparing the values.since i am getting the value as long i directly used the compareTo function to do this.avoided the conversion of long to string and string to date conversion.thank you all for support.