# how to convert long date value to mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: java, android, date, data-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [converting long string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753341/converting-long-string-to-date)

I need to convert **long** date value to **mm/dd/yyyy** format.my long value is

```
strDate1="1346524199000"
```

please help me

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753341/converting-long-string-to-date for a possible duplicate of your own question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11753341/converting-long-string-to-date this is long string to date convertion..i need long to date covertion..

Comment: So where is the long datatype here. I could see only string data type. So it literally means that both the questions share the same idea. YOu have not shown any point which shows a long data type.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Refer Below code which give the date in String form.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;



public class Test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long val = 1346524199000l;
        Date date=new Date(val);
        SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
        String dateText = df2.format(date);
        System.out.println(dateText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Date date=new Date(1346524199000l); it will always give year 1970

Comment: Anyone who is having 1970 date from this code, please check your timestamp is in miliseconds. A timestamp for recent years should have 13 digits in it. If yours has 10 that means, you need to multiply by 1000.

Answer (score 8):

Refer below code for formatting date

```
long strDate1 = 1346524199000;
Date date = new Date(strDate1);

try {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
        SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
        date = df2.format(format.parse("yourdate");
    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this example

```
 String[] formats = new String[] {
   "yyyy-MM-dd",
   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",
   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ",
   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
 };
 for (String format : formats) {
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format, Locale.US);
   System.err.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(new Date(0)));
   sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
   System.err.format("%30s %s\n", format, sdf.format(new Date(0)));
 }
```

and read this http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public class test 
{  

    public static void main(String a[])
    {  
        long tmp = 1346524199000;  

        Date d = new Date(tmp);  
        System.out.println(d);  
    }  
}
```