# Conversion of milliseconds to a specific date format

Tags: java, datetime-format

How can I convert the current time in milliseconds, which is a `Long`, to a date in specific format?

The format that I need is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm`. This should be of type `Date`, not `String`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to convert long date value to mm/dd/yyyy format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755534/how-to-convert-long-date-value-to-mm-dd-yyyy-format)

Answer (score 3):

You are confused. The type `Date` is a number of milliseconds since January 1 1970 midnight UTC. It has no inherent format. There is a default system format for a Date, but you cannot alter it. You will need to format your `Date` as a `String` if you need that particular `String` format.